# Why when i specified a width property in my p element the text doesn't flow around the div element? Using floats

Tags: html, css

Why when I specify a **width property** in my p element, the text doesn't flow around the div element ?
I know one the solution to this is to have  float: left; in my p element too. Just looking for explanation, not finding for solution

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.2;
  float: left;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
  width:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Comment: @isherwood sorry I wrote wrong, I meant flow around the <div> element. Just a little confused, am not finding for solution but explanation. Why when I specify a width in the <p> element the text doesn't flow to the right of the <div> element anymore. But without the width it flow to the right of it.

Comment: Looks to me like it _does_ flow around the div, at least within the constraints you've provided. I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: @isherwood ok umm, when you remove the width property from the <p> element. The text will flow around the <div> element ( the text will move to the right of the square box ). The thing that confused me is that why when you add width property ( any size even 1px ) back, the text won't be at the right of the square box anymore. The text will be below the square box.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You can see the area the text is allotted with the yellow color. That doesn't extend right of the div. Why would you expect the text to be _outside_ its paragraph?

Comment: @isherwood i get it now xD. The width of <p> element is smaller than the <div> element that's why is under the box and why the text is under not to the right. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: Yep. Please take the [tour] and respond to your answers accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block elements don't wrap around floats, their contained line boxes do. But since the width of the p element is less than that of the div element, there's no space for the line boxes of the p element to go beside the div element, so the first opportunity for the line box to be placed is below the div element. So wrapping around is exactly what the line box of the p element is doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a display issue.
You can try to set a `display:inline-block` to your `<p>` tag.

But I think to put one aside another you can better use flex-box:

Wrap your two or more elements inside a div or a section, and give this div a property `display: flex`.
By default, it will align those elements horizontally, and the property `align-items: center` is to align those elements based on the div's center.

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <p>Another</p>
</div>

<style>
  
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#container div {
  /* ... Your previous div style */
  margin-right: 15px;
}

</style>
```